# DataStage 11.7 : Aggregator compilation error

Tags: aggregate-functions, aggregation, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I am performing aggregation on a set of 16 columns. But while compiling the jobs below error is shown
"no derivation found for column '%1' in aggregator" .

my job design is simple.  source --> Transform --> aggregator --> Target(file)

Can anyone help me out with this. I have checked the columns and metadata and I don't see this '%1' column there.
Googled also and didn't find any info on this particular error.